# Python scrapy content encoding

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy

I have very simple scrupy project but the issue is I'm trying to parse site with non-english (russian) content. My Spider is:

```
class MdsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mds_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://mds-club.ru"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://mds-club.ru/cgi-bin/index.cgi?r=84&lang=rus/catalog",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css('#catalogtable tbody tr'):
            item = MdsItem()
            item['author'] = row.css('td:nth-child(2) a::text').extract()
            item['name'] = row.css('td:nth-child(3) a::text').extract()
            yield item
```

and after running it I have strings like

```
{'author': [u'\u042d\u0440\u0438\u043a \u0424\u0440\u044d\u043d\u043a \u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0435\u043b']
```

Note that string itself is unicode however it's content is strange. 
Also response.encoding=cp1251 if it helps

I want to see strings in console in normal readable way, what am I doing wrong ?

p.s. In the doc I found info about setting DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS in settings - that didn't helped.

Comment: Is this the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436496/scrapy-issue-with-encoding-when-dumping-to-the-json-file/23460465 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Try item['author'] = row.css('td:nth-child(2) a::text').extract()[0]. 
It will give you first object of a list in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Try encode and decoding using cp1251:

```
x = u'\u0418\u0433\u0440\u0430 \u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432'
y = x.encode("cp1251","ignore").decode("cp1251","ignore")
```

y will be: u"Игра престолов"